# Use data-* attribute in grails g.link generated in tagLib

Tags: grails

Is there a way to use data- attributes in g.link generated by a tagLib? I want to store some DOM info instead of using params in the g.link which results in query parameters.

Example:

```
out << g.link(controller: "calendar", action: "info", params: [id: cal_id], data-info: "abc") { "click me " }
```

Unfortunately this works only when using the normal g.link syntax from the view:

```
<g:link controller="calendar" action="info" id="${cal_id}" data-info="abc">click me</g:link>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put quotes around your data attributes :

```
out << g.link(controller: "calendar", action: "info", params: [id: cal_id], "data-info": "abc") { "click me " }
```